# Launch activity module from main App Android

Tags: android, android-activity, module, android-manifest

I'm trying to launch an Activity on a module I imported from my main app.
Nothing is happening. No crash and no launch. Here is my code on my main app:

```
Intent moduleActivity = new Intent("com.service.ModuleActivity");
startActivity(moduleActivity);
```

Here is the module manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:persistent="true" >

    <activity android:name="com.service.ModuleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.service.ModuleActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have no crash and on debug the `Intent moduleActivity` is not `null`
What did I miss ?

Comment: Hi Dev, try to replace line Intent moduleActivity = new Intent("com.service.ModuleActivity"); with Intent moduleActivity = new Intent(context, ModuleActivity.class);

Comment: The one parameter Intent constructor is for specifying an action, like VIEW.  You don't use it to specify a class name.

Comment: @RishabhBhatia Nothing happen also with new Intent(context, ModuleActivity.class);

Comment: @DevAndroid If you open ModuleActivity and verify the package name on top. Does it say com.service?

Comment: @RishabhBhatia Yes everything is correct on names.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved it..

```
Intent moduleActivity = new Intent("com.service.ModuleActivity");
moduleActivity .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //by adding this line
startActivity(moduleActivity);
```

Thanks all

Comment: This error would have been showing in your LogCat https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html